# Can we know email address of all users who downloaded our iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am new to iPhone Apps.

Do we get the know the email address of all the users who bought our iPhone App through App Store?

Also, when we submit our app for review, do we have to submit the App Description, price and other details? OR we do this after our app is approved by them?

Please let me know.

Comment: if you call the customer support of some ISP and why your email address you never tell any people or any website is getting spammed, the supervisor of the customer support may tell you -- "IT IS DUE TO COOKIES"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow you access to any information about the folks who have downloaded your app, so you won't be able to get email addresses. You can, however, request inside the app that users sign up for a mailing list, or require them to create an account on your server to play.

About submitting for review, you fill in all details before submitting the binary. If you don't have this stuff ready yet, you can fill in placeholder text for the app, and change it later before the app goes live. the two details that do get locked in are **App Name** and **keywords**, so be careful and make sure you like these, as you'll have to submit a new build to change them.